# Microsoft Excel - Creating Shortcuts using Macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I recently created a shortcut in Excel using the "Record Macros" option. The shortcut was for centering text across a selection of cells.

What I would like to know is once I have used the shortcut for centering the text, how do I then undo that action and not have the text centered across the selection. I have tried Ctrl + Z but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There is no way to automatically undo what has been done by a macro. Instead, consider creating a Style that sets horizontal alignment to "Center Across Selection". Then you can apply the style to the cells that you want and you use Undo to change it back.

Comment: Ok I'll try this as well. Seems simpler than recording Macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no as such Command available to reverse the effects of the Macro like we do have Ctrl+Z. But there are certain effective methods which could Terminate or Stop the Macro.

To Terminate the Macro use **Ctrl+Alt+Break.**

To Stop the Macro use **ESC + End.**

**Note,** in your case you need to write and Run one more Macro to revert the effects of previous one.

For example, your Macro Centers the text so, you need to write VBA Code line to 'Select the same Text and Re-align it to it's previous state'.

*Hope it help you.*

Comment: Thank You for the answer. As i am new to excel and have no experience with coding at all, could you kindly assist me as to how to reverse the effects of the Macro?

Comment: Nice to hear from you, You copy and paste the Macro you have recorded,, then I'll re-write the "Reverse Code" for that.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to copy the code for the Recorded Macro (I am absolutely new to all this). I'll research a bit on this and get back with the code. Thanks!